# Java | Validating JSON objects inside wrapper

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I am working with Java Spring framework and receive a JSON on input. It consists of an array of thousands of `MyObjects`. I would like the application to throw exception if one of the `MyObjects` or `AnotherObjects` fails a constraint (`@NotNull` or `@Size`).
So far, the application throws `NullPointerException` once it is accessing the `null` field when doing something with the object - not during its construction.

My question is:

> Is there a way to check the constraints of nested JSON objects preferrably with annotation?

The JSON looks like:

```
{
  "myObjects": [
    {
      "code": "PQ",
      "another_objects": [
        {
          "attr1": "value1",
          "attr2": "value2",
          "attrN": "valueN"
        },
        {
          "attr1": "value1",
          "attr2": "value2",
          "attrN": "valueN"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The servlet looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ...)
public final void doSomething(@Valid @RequestBody MyObjectWrapper wrapper) {
    // do something very time-heavy here
}
```

The objects are defined as follows:

```
public class MyObjectWrapper {
    private List<MyObject> myObjects;

    public List<MyObject> getMyObjects() {
        return myObjects;
    }

    public void setMyObjects(List<MyObjects> myObjects) {
        this.myObjects = myObjects;
    }
}
```

And the MyObject class:

```
public class MyObject {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = ...)
    List<AnotherObject> anotherObjects;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 2, message = ...)
    String code;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyObject(@JsonProperty("another_objects") List<AnotherObjects> anotherObjects,
                    @JsonProperty("code") String code) {
        this.code = code;
        this.anotherObjects = anotherObjects;
    }

    /*  getters and setters */
}
```

The AnotherObjects is similar but consists of Strings only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `@Valid` to the nested object of the wrapper

```
public class MyObjectWrapper {
    @Valid
    private List<MyObject> myObjects;

    public List<MyObject> getMyObjects() {
        return myObjects;
    }

    public void setMyObjects(List<MyObjects> myObjects) {
        this.myObjects = myObjects;
    }
}
```